# get value by name in relational database

Tags: laravel

by using this code in resource file

```
@forelse($teachers as $teacher)
    {{$teacher->name}} {{$teacher->subjects}}<br>
    @empty
    Nothing
    @endforelse
```

getting this value

```
helooo [{"id":3,"name":"Hindi","created_at":"2017-11-18 12:43:33","updated_at":"2017-11-18 12:43:33","pivot":{"teacher_id":16,"subject_id":3}}]
malik [{"id":2,"name":"English","created_at":"2017-11-18 12:43:12","updated_at":"2017-11-18 12:43:12","pivot":{"teacher_id":17,"subject_id":2}}]
hello [{"id":1,"name":"Maths","created_at":"2017-11-18 12:42:34","updated_at":"2017-11-18 12:42:34","pivot":{"teacher_id":18,"subject_id":1}}]
```

but by using

```
 {{$teacher->name}} {{$teacher->subjects->name}}
```

getting error

```
Property [name] does not exist on this collection instance
```

how can i get just the name value in laravel

Comment: Not sure from the information you give, but have you tried: $teacher->subjects()->name

Comment: just echo $teacher in blade and check what it contains.

Comment: @mwal its still giving an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's many to many, you need to iterate over subjects of each teacher:

```
@forelse($teachers as $teacher)
    {{ $teacher->name }}<br>
    @foreach ($teacher->subjects as $subject)
        {{ $subject->name }}<br>
    @endforeach
@empty
    Nothing
@endforelse
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the data that is being returned is an object in an array. Try adding a zero to select the first obj in this arr. Like this:

```
$teacher->subjects[0]->name
```

Good luck!